# Generalized Holder Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, proof-writing, products

Let $a_i \in \mathbb R^n$ with $a_i = (a_{i}^j)_{j = 1 ... n} = (a_{i}^1, ... ,a_{i}^n)$ for $i = 1, ... , k$ and let $p_1,...,p_k \in \mathbb R_{>1}$ with $\frac1{p_1}+ ... + \frac1{p_k} = 1$

Then show the following inequality by assuming that there are for every $i = 1, ... ,k$ one $N \in \mathbb N_{>1}$ and one $n_i \in \{1,...,2^N\}$ with $p_i = 2^N / n_i$:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n|\prod_{i=1}^ka_{i}^j| \leq \prod_{i=1}^k(\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{i}^j|^{p_i})^{1 \over {p_i}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Source: Hojoo Lee, "Topics in Inequalities - Theorems and Techniques" (February 25, 2006), p.44.

Comment: tnx!!! you`re saving the day and the night